# Why are components hard to insert into a breadboard?

Tags: breadboard

I have just bought a breadboard, but I have notinced that the components are hard to insert into the holes (and sometimes only one pin go in and the another one go out, like a LED).
In videos I see people insert componenets into breadboard very easily.

---

Is it normal because it is a new breadboard?
Will it be fixed soon ?
Any way to make inserting compomemts easier?
I tried to use a jumber wire to help making holes bigger, but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this happen to me and it was essentially a faulty breadboard. The components should easily go in and out if the breadboard is good. I have managed to loosen up my bad breadboards by forcing large tough component legs(like pin header) into and out of the stiff holes repeatedly, they eventually become more accepting of parts.

If it is really bad you may just need another breadboard.

Comment: Indeed - it's probably non-trivial to calibrate the machinery for making a contacts, and the failed units where this was not done have shown up on the market.  Also beware of end-pin wire kits, as those can have flat ends more likely to damage contacts than insert into them.

Answer (score 1):

problem solved by using a male jumber wire, I put then remove it in every hole (and reapeted it 3 times).
I will also try using a pin header as HighInBC mentiond

Comment: You should not have to do this unless the breadboard was mismanufactured.

Comment: Mismanufactured breadboards are unfortunately common.

Comment: I've bought another breadboard and it was so easy to use it (also after doing what I said).

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you are using the correct AWG(gauge/thickness) of wire. Normal jumper cables are 22AWG, and they fit fine. If you are using 22AWG wire(it should be written on the wire), then it's a problem with your board, and you should return it and get a new one.You can buy one [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Solderless-MB-102-MB102-Breadboard-830-Tie-Point-PCB-BreadBoard-For-Arduino-X5RN-/391315128246?hash=item5b1c32ffb6:g:UW8AAOSw4HVWCcJk) for about $2.50 and there's 820 pins.